# Hello, I want to get the value of the second <value> if the value of first <value> is Properties.Name (I need to get both of them)

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xml);

XmlNodeList values = doc.GetElementsByTagName("value");

string result = "Properties.Name";

foreach (XmlNode xnode in values)
{
    if (xnode.InnerText == result)
    {
        Console.Write(Next.InnerText + ", ");
    }
}
```

My XML data:

```
<properties name="prop">
    <property>
        <type>0</type>
        <dataType>0</dataType>
        <key>key</key>
        <value>Properties.Name</value>
        <readOnly>0</readOnly>
    </property>
    <property>
        <type>0</type>
        <dataType>0</dataType>
        <key>value</key>
        <value>Image1</value>
        <readOnly>0</readOnly>
    </property>
    <properties name="prop">
        <property>
            <type>0</type>
            <dataType>0</dataType>
            <key>key</key>
            <value>Properties.Name</value>
            <readOnly>0</readOnly>
        </property>
        <property>
            <type>0</type>
            <dataType>0</dataType>
            <key>value</key>
            <value>Text1</value>
            <readOnly>0</readOnly>
        </property>
```

Expected: Base1, Image1

Actual: Properties.Name, Properties.Name

Comment: Please include all relevant information here instead of linking to off-site resources that likely will get stale quickly.

Comment: There is no "Base1" in your XML

Comment: Also, your xml is not valid xml.

Comment: next sibling would be key, not a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have broken XML in request with misleading points, i try to create coupule examples to approach:

```
string xml = "<plist>"
        + "<properties name=\"prop\">"
        + "<property><type>0</type><dataType>0</dataType><key>key</key><value>Properties.Name</value><readOnly>0</readOnly></property>"
        + "<property><type>0</type><dataType>0</dataType><key>value</key><value>Image1</value><readOnly>0</readOnly></property>"
        + "</properties>"
        + "<properties name=\"prop\">"
        + "<property><type>0</type><dataType>0</dataType><key>key</key><value>Properties.Name</value><readOnly>0</readOnly></property>"
        + "<property><type>0</type><dataType>0</dataType><key>value</key><value>Text1</value><readOnly>0</readOnly></property>"
        + "</properties>"
        + "</plist>";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    XmlNodeList values = doc.GetElementsByTagName("value");
    string result = "Properties.Name";

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        if (values[i].InnerText == result)
        {
            Console.Write(values[i + 1].InnerText + ", ");
            i++;
        }

    Console.WriteLine("\n\n another way:");

    var lst = values.Cast<XmlNode>().ToList();

    lst.ForEach(f => {
        if(f.InnerText==result)
        Console.WriteLine(lst[lst.IndexOf(f)+1].InnerText + ", ");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Power Mouse! That was exactly what i was looking for.